# python unittest not working as expected for fast api methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am testing a `fast API` method where some calls have been made. Actual logic resides in the downstream layers. Now, I am trying to test that method(mentioned below) using Python unit test but it doesn't work as expected

```
app = FastAPI()
snowflake_factory = SnowflakeProvisionerApiFactory()
snowflake_provisioner_outputport = snowflake_factory.create_outputport()
snowflake_provisioner_workload = snowflake_factory.create_workload()
logger = get_provisioner_logger()
provisioner_utility = ProvisionerUtility()


@app.post("/ss/v1/provision")
async def output_port_provision(request: Request):
    try:
        data = await request.json()
        provisioning_request = ProvisioningRequest(**data)
        logger.info("ss Provision Request: %s", str(provisioning_request))
        provision_request = provisioner_utility.parse_yaml_outputport(provisioning_request.descriptor)
        result = snowflake_provisioner_outputport.provision(provision_request)
        response = provisioner_utility.response(200, ProvisioningStatus(Status.COMPLETED.name, str(result)))
        logger.info("ss Provision Response: %s", str(response))
        return response
    except (ValidationException, TypeError) as e:
        logger.error("validation error raised: %s", str(e))
        validation_err = ValidationErr([str(e)])
        return provisioner_utility.response(400, validation_err)
    except SystemException as e:
        logger.critical("system exception: %s", str(e))
        return provisioner_utility.response(500, SystemErr(str(e)))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.critical("system exception: %s", str(e))
        return provisioner_utility.response(500, SystemErr(str(e)))
```

Now, below is the test case that I wrote and it doesn't call the `assert_called_once_with` statement.

```
def test_demo_api(self):
    with patch('app.app.output_port_provision') as mocked_post:

        request_payload = {
            'httpMethod': 'POST',
            'path': '/outputport/v1/provision',
            'pathParameters': {},
            'body': '{"descriptorKind":"my_desc_kind",'
                    '"descriptor": '
                    '"dataProduct:\\n'
                    "   id: id\\n"
                    "   dataProductOwner: dataProductOwner\\n"
                    "   devGroup: bigdata\\n"
                    "   ownerGroup: bigdata\\n"
                    "   specific: {}\\n"
                    "component:\\n"
                    "   specific:\\n"
                    "     schema: my-schema\\n"
                    "     table: my-table\\n"
                    '"}',
            'isBase64Encoded': 'false'
        }
        self.client.post("/ss/v1/provision", json=request_payload.get('body'))
        mocked_post.provision.assert_called_once_with(request_payload)
```

So what exactly am I missing here? Any help or reference is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.